Cross-platform method to determine text width
At the moment I've got the following method which I'm using to determine the text size in my WPF app, used when generating some Excel reports:
// see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268620/openxml-auto-size-column-width-in-excel
private static double GetTextWidth(string text)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    using var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    using var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 10F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    var pixelWidth = graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
    //see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716078/formula-to-convert-net-pixels-to-excel-width-in-openxml-format/7902415
    var openXmlWidth = (pixelWidth - 12 + 5) / 7d + 1;
    return openXmlWidth;
}

As you can see from the comments, I'm already taking some hints from other SO questions, namely this one and this one. But, really, the latter isn't as important as the former (the latter is just a bit of math, so not a problem for this case).
I'd like to move my Excel code so it's not "WPF, client-side" but rather server-side, and here I want the server to either be a Windows machine OR a Linux machine, i.e. I need the code to be cross-platform compatible.
Alas, I'm not sure what I can use to measure the pixel-width of text which isn't going to be Windows-dependant...
The problem here is that a lot of the classes from the code-snippet above seem to be Windows-dependant. I.e. the compiler throws a lot of warnings at me, such as:
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Graphics.MeasureString(string?, Font)' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Graphics.TextRenderingHint' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'FontStyle.Regular' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'GraphicsUnit.Pixel' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'GraphicsUnit.Point' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Bitmap' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Graphics.PageUnit' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Font' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Graphics.FromImage(Image)' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416)

I've no reason not to trust the compiler warning in this case. Plus I've also found this MS document on stopping cross-compatibility of System.Drawing.
Are there any libraries or classes I can use for this? Or is the compiler warning "wrong", and this will work perfectly fine on a Linux server?
PS. BTW - the code is used to calculate if a given text "fits" into an Excel cell of specific width; if it does not then a different text is used. I.e. I don't want to use Excel's "native" truncate-text-so-it-fits logic.

@stuartd Graphics.MeasureString(string?, Font)' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later. - that's why. I'll edit the question to indicate why the current code will likely not work.

Also this MS documentation states how they're stopping cross-platform compatibility for System.Drawing...

ah sorry. That article takes about using Imagesharp, there is a Text Measurer in one of their packages?

You can measure text with Sixlabors.Fonts.TextMeasurer and it will be cross-platform. Note, that the measurement result will only match only the Sixlabors.Fonts text renderer and may not match with the system renderer (so may not be usable for your task)

@Serg That works. If you want you can write that as an answer? Otherwise I can "answer myself" using your comment as a jumping off point?

@MBender, I added a basic sample. If you have more mature solution, feel free to post and accept it.

You can measure text with Sixlabors.Fonts.TextMeasurer and it will be cross-platform. The basic implementation may be following (I have omitted the openXML-related corrections). The code tested on windows.
private static double GetTextWidth(string text)
{
    var font = GetFont("Calibri",10, FontStyle.Regular);
    var fontSize = TextMeasurer.MeasureSize("your Text", new TextOptions(font));
    return fontSize.Width;
}

private static Font GetFont(string fontName, float size, FontStyle style)
{
    var fontPath = GetFontPath(fontName);
    var collection = new FontCollection();
    var family = collection.Add(fontPath);
    var font = family.CreateFont(size, style);
    return font;
}


private static string GetFontPath(string fontName)
{
    //TODO: implement platform-specific font location code
    //or just bundle a font with your app
    var fontsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);
    return Path.Combine(fontsFolder, $"{fontName}.ttf");
}

Notes:

that the measurement result will only match only the Sixlabors.Fonts text renderer and may not match with the system renderer (so may not be usable for your task)
the library does not have any built-in way to access system fonts. So, you will need to write the code to locate font file for the current system manually.


Based of the comment by @Serg I've decided to give Sixlabors.Fonts Nuget a try and found a working solution.
The relevant code is fairly short:
private static double GetTextWidth(string text)
{
    var pixelWidth = TextMeasurer.MeasureSize(text, LoadTextMeasuringOptions()).Width;
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716078/formula-to-convert-net-pixels-to-excel-width-in-openxml-format/7902415
    var openXmlWidth = (pixelWidth - 12 + 5) / 7d + 1;
    return openXmlWidth;
}

private static TextOptions LoadTextMeasuringOptions()
{
    var fontCollection = new FontCollection();
    using var fontStream = TemplateManager.OpenTemplateAsStream(TemplateManager.CalibriFont);
    var family = fontCollection.Add(fontStream);
    var textOptions = new TextOptions(family.CreateFont(10F, FontStyle.Regular)) { Dpi = 90 };
    return textOptions;
}

The only custom component in here is the TemplateManager.OpenTempalteAsStream method which accesses embedded resources. In this case I've included the calibri.ttf as an embedded resource to make sure it's available.
public static Stream OpenTemplateAsStream(string templateName)
{
    var assembly = typeof(TemplateManager).Assembly;
    return assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(templateName) ?? throw new NullReferenceException($"Could not find embedded stream {templateName}");
}

The way this code is structured is not optimal for a more generic use-case. The loading of the font in the LoadTextMeasuringOptions method is relatively slow, so depending on the use-case some restructuring might be required, and the font parameters are hard-coded. In the actual code I'm using Lazy loading to ensure this operation is performed only once. But it shouldn't be difficult to rework this if more sizes or more fonts are needed.
Finally, I did some testing and found that I had to change the DPI of the TextOptions to make the results "similar" to the TextMeasurer.MeasureSize results.
