# C# Measure Width and Height of Google font character

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fonts, font-size, google-font-api

i am trying to measure single chars of different fonts from **Google fonts**. 
I tried a lot, but the proportion of height and width was always wrong... 
Here are some of my attempts:

1. TextRenderer

font:= the bloburi of a Google font-example: "https://github.com/FontFaceKit/open-sans/blob/gh-pages/fonts/Bold/OpenSans-Bold.ttf?raw=true"

```
        FontRequestHelper helper = new FontRequestHelper(font);
        iFontCollection = helper.iFontCollection;
        FontStyle style = iFontCollection.Families[0].IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold) ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular;
        System.Drawing.Font googlefont = new System.Drawing.Font(iFontCollection.Families[0], tSize, FontStyle.Regular);
        size = TextRenderer.MeasureText("A", googlefont);
```

2. MeasureString

i tried different ones, always not accurated...

```
      SizeF sizeFf = new SizeF();
      using (var image = new Bitmap(1, 1))
       {
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                sizeFf = g.MeasureString("A", googlefont);
            }
        }
```

or

```
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            sizeFf = g.MeasureString("A", googlefont);
        }
```

I dont need the exact width and height, the right proportion would be also reasonable. Online i only find this two solutions as good... Why does it not work for me?

Thx a lot

Comment: If they are not monospace font then measuring any character will give you different result, try measuring W for example in most fonts it is wider than A, and font reserves some space on both sides. Check for example this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833062/how-to-measure-the-pixel-width-of-a-digit-in-a-given-font-size-c.

Comment: yea i know that, and thats why i need the exact proportional of every char in every font. But my methods given the wrong width/height prop, if i rechecked a font in paint.NET f. e....

Comment: then I can only thing of rendering character to bitmap and finding bounding box, slow but may be accurate when you use big font size.